# I'm using wordpress plugin prime slider I need to change the navigation menu from buttons to text how can I do that?

Tags: wordpress

Refer to this image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zpLz.png)
The navigation menu is on the right instead of dots I want to make it as a text How can I exactly achieve this is there any new plugin or I can do it in the dashboard itself. I tried css it did not help !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.